# How to restore Sublime Text settings and preferences and undo the symlink created in Dropbox?

Tags: macos, unix, sublimetext2, dropbox, symlink

How can I restore Sublime Text settings and preferences and undo the symlink created in Dropbox? I cannot access the Sublime Text 2 preferences on my machine after creating a symlink in Dropbox.

These are the commands I ran on my primary machine:

```
cd ~/Dropbox
ln -s ~/'Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2' sublime-text-2-settings
```

These created "sublime-text-2-settings" in the Dropbox root directory.

Then on a second machine, I ran the following commands:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\2/
rm -R Packages
ln -s ~/Dropbox/sublime-text-2-settings Packages
```

This is from: https://github.com/Rowno/rolandwarmerdam.co.nz/blob/master/app/_posts/2013-01-09-sync-sublime-text-2-settings.md

Now, Sublime Text 2 on both machines is being rendered in a total black and white color scheme, the black sidebar too, so it's impossible to view files. Also, I cannot access the Preferences on either machine making it impossible to move forward.

- How can I undo the symlink?
- How can I access Preferences on my primary machine?

I spent hours customizing Preferences and adding packages and I would hate to loose it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved for now (by brute force).

1. Unlink symbolic link (unlink /path/to/sym/link) (on both machines)
2. Copy + Paste - Packages folder in ~/'Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2' sublime-text-2-settings on the primary machine.
3. Reinstall Sublime Text on secondary machine.
4. Restart Sublime on both machines.

Aaand, back in action!

Though #3 and #4 didn't have to be in that particular order. It seems that the main problem was that the Packages folder got moved on the primary machine and were completely replaced by the symbolic link on the second machine. The symbolic link was also missing the Packages folder since it had moved on the primary machine before the symbolic link was created.

Comment: If you run again in this issue, try removing "Theme - Soda" from ignored_packages array in Prefrences -> "Settings User" (https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/issues/159)