# What & how to version control for text editor (Sublime Text) settings on Github, so that settings are readily available for coding on any machine?

Tags: version-control, github, sublimetext2, development-environment, text-editor

[I almost lost all my Sublime settings last night](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455052/how-to-restore-sublime-text-settings-preferences-and-undo-the-symlink-created). I know some people store their text editor settings for VIM and/or Sublime on Github. This I assume allows for a quick clone on any machine - making any machine readily available with all your settings, key bindings, packages etc.

1. How do you store your text editor (Sublime Text 2) settings on
   Github, so that you can reuse your settings on any machine?
2. What files/folders need to be put on Git?
3. What will be the procedure of "packaging" up all these settings on a new machine?

Comment: There is a nice, easy to follow and comprehensive tutorial at https://medium.com/@devmount/using-git-to-sync-sublime-text-settings-f70b8dc7a40d by @devmounton how to back you sublime text settings to Github. Hope it helps. Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set the `Packages/` directory as the base for your repository, as all settings (except the license), [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages) plugins, themes, etc. are in its subfolders. I have my license in my gmail so I can look it up from wherever.

As a warning, just make sure you don't have any sensitive information in any of your settings, like server passwords and the like, as unless you've paid for a private Github repository anyone at all can see your settings.

Comment: The whole package directory is, in most cases, overkill. If you are using package control, it will install any missing packages in the `installed_packages` list when you start Sublime Text. I'd recommend just copying the `Packages/User/` directory to GitHub, then sym linking to that on new machines.  As MattDMo mentioned, make sure you don't place "secret information" on github. Of course, you have custom plugins that are not hosted on github or bitbucket in the packages folder, you would need to do the entire Packages directory.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I'll experiment with that idea. Though with this approach, I can foresee a few manual steps w.r.t. to Part 3 of my question: having to backup /renaming the Packages folder on another machine and then replacing it with the Packages folder in source control. I'm hoping to get this to work with the help of symbolic links. Very new to the idea of symlinks so not sure about the best way to add them / implement.

Comment: Thanks, @skuroda.That's really good to know and makes a lot of sense - wonder which approach w.r.t to installed_packages will be better to hit the ground running faster. Symlinks are starting to make sense - they are like shortcuts in Windows.

Comment: @skuroda I mentioned the whole `Packages` directory because not all plugins are good about keeping the user config files in `Packages/User`, and while `Installed Packages` only has the Package Control plugin (for me), `Packages/` has maybe 50 subdirectories - Package Control plugins, different language definitions, personal development stuff, etc.

Comment: @sojourner - If you back up all of `Packages/`, you can do a fresh install of Sublime, completely delete the `Packages/` it comes with, and replace with your own. You wouldn't necessarily need to mess around with symlinks.

Comment: @MattDMo - many thanks. Unfortunately I don't have enough points yet - to upvote your answer. I'll get to experiment with it all - later this week - will let you know how it goes!

Comment: @MattDMo True. Like I said, if you have custom plugins you will need the whole directory. Personally, I host all my stuff on github and manually add it as a repository to package control. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "plugins keeping settings in the user folder". They should be using `sublime.load_settings()` to get configurations, which searches the user directory also.

Comment: I would like to add Package Control documentation on how to accomplish such task from this [link](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing).